# Group theory and binary operations

Tags: group-theory

In the set of real numbers, I have the following binary operations, $*$ and $\otimes$.

I know that: $x * y = |x-y|$    and   $x \otimes y = |x|⋅y$

I have found out that $*$ and $⊗$ can neither be associative or commutative, but they do have a neutral element, defined as
$$
x * e = e * x = x
$$
$$
x * e = e * x = |x - 0| = |0 -x |  =  x
$$
And that
$$
x ⊗ e = e ⊗ x = x
$$
$$
x ⊗ e = e ⊗ x = |x|⋅1 = 1⋅|x|  =  x
$$
Is my logic correct?

Comment: What makes you think that $*$ can't be commutative? If you take $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ then $x*y = |x - y| = |-(x-y)| = |y-x| = y*x$

Comment: * is commutative. This is too many questions. Write out your work and ask one at a time only about places where you are unsure.

Comment: That makes sense, * is commutative, but ⊗ is not.

Comment: also, is the set you're working in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ because if you look at $x=-3$ then $x*e = -3*e= |-3 - 0| = |-3| = 3 \neq x$ so your argument fails at that point

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not convinced that $1$ is a neutral element for $\otimes$.

After all: $-3 \otimes 1 = 3 \neq -3$

Answer (score 1):

$0$ is not a neutral element for $*$ if you take all real numbers, since

$$0*-1=|0-(-1)|=|1|=1\ne -1$$